# How is GCam APK Port created?

Tags: camera, google-camera

Google Camera app is the application responsible for taking photos and recording videos and is only available for Google Pixel smartphone. It offers many great features such as such as HDR+, color enhancement, Super Res Zoom, Night Mode, and much more. This enables users to take amazing photos,even in low-light situations.

To use features from Google Camera app on Android smartphones from other vendors, GCam APK Port is created. Google Camera app is a closed source software.How does GCam APK Port have such capability? Google must use its own proprietary technologies for its features. How can
other apps access to the technologies? Does Google provide interfaces to use the technologies?

I searched the internet and found the following:

> GCam APK Port refers to a modified version of the Google Camera app that has been ported to work on non-Pixel devices. These ports are created by developers who modify the original Google Camera app to make it compatible with a wider range of Android smartphones.

But I don't understand what these sentences mean.  What do they mean?

Comment: Not sure what you don't understand on that quote. It just describes the general process of how a manufacturer specific app is modified so that it also works on device of different manufacturers. As this process can be very complex it just gives you an overview how it works in general. If you want to understand app modification try to modify an app using apktool yourself (note that you need development skills and a lot of time to learn this).

Comment: Sorry, I am not a app developer, so I am not familiar with the process. Do you mean that the source code of Google Camera app is accessoible to developers?If so, developer can   make modifications to run the app on  Android smartphones from other vendors? Is the code of proprietary algorithms of features such as HDR+ is in binary mode? Only the interfaces to proprietary algorithms  is accessoible to developers? In summary, proprietary algorithms is closed source and the wrapper or the framework of the algorithms is open source?

Comment: No, the source code of GCam is not available but with enough effort plus knowledge and skill you can modify any program. On Android you have the DEX code which can be decompiled to Smali and native .so libraries can be decompiled to assembler and thus understood and modified. What exactly needs to be modified in case of GCam is only known to the developers who perform the modifications.